# DynamicListRoute with Custom Router - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

## What I've done (working)

**ModelViewSet**:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset for viewing and editing user instances.
    """
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsUser]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    @list_route(methods=['GET','PUT'])
    def me(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs.update(pk=request.user.id)
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return self.retrieve(request,*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return self.update(request,*args, **kwargs)
```

Notes:

- `UserSerializer` is a simple ModelSerializer for a User object.
- `IsUser` is a permission class that verifies if `obj.id == request.user.id`

**SimpleRouter**:

```
router = SimpleRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Note:

- The path doesn't start here, but I will assume it does to name the endpoints.

So now I've got the routes described in the [SimpleRouter Documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter), that are basically every conventional endpoint, plus:

- URL Style: `users/me`
- HTTP Method: GET and PUT (as specified by `methods` argument)
- Action: `me` (`@list_route` decorated method)
- URL Name: `user-me`

**My Requests**

- `GET /users/me` returning a JSON encoded User object.
- `PUT /users/me` updating the User object and returning the updated JSON encoded User object.

## What I want (not working)

I don't need, and don't want, all the routes created by `SimpleRouter`.

**Custom router**

```
class CustomRetrieveUpdateRouter(SimpleRouter):
    routes = [
        Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}/{lookup}{trailing_slash}$',
            mapping={'get': 'retrieve'},
            name='{basename}-detail',
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'Detail'}
        ),
        Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}/{lookup}{trailing_slash}$',
            mapping={'put': 'update'},
            name='{basename}-detail',
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'Detail'}
        ),
        DynamicListRoute(
            url=r'^{prefix}/{methodname}{trailing_slash}$',
            name='{basename}-{methodnamehyphen}',
            initkwargs={}
        )
    ]
```

**My Requests**

- `GET /users/me` returning the following JSON body: `{"detail":"Not found."}` and a `404` Error Code.
- `PUT /users/me` returning the following JSON body: `{"detail":"Method \"PUT\" not allowed."}` and a `405` Error Code.

Note:

In Debug if I do a request that returns 404, the HTML page displays the following available endpoints:

- `^users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)$ [name='user-detail']`
- `^users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)$ [name='user-detail']`
- `^users/me$ [name='user-me']`

What am I forgetting?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can call ../users/me" ? Can you be more specific ?

Comment: When I do a GET request to that endpoint I receive a 200 response with the appropriate JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have conflict in your routes.

`^users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)$` should catch "/users/me" and therefore it won't have a chance to hit your specific view.

Either set the pk url kwargs regexp to something more specific (like integers for id) or set the DynamicListRoute before the two other `Route`.